# Options page not showing up

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I cant see this menu names in admin menu list. 
This plugin just show me **Custom fields** on the menu. 
Whats wrong on this code ?

What I have in functions.php file

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Site Ayarları',
        'menu_title'    => 'Site Ayarları',
        'menu_slug'     => 'site-ayarlari',
        'capability'    => 'manage_options',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));

    acf_add_options_page(array(
        'page_title'    => 'Ana Sayfa Ayarları',
        'menu_title'    => 'Ana Sayfa Ayarları',
        'menu_slug'     => 'anasayfa-ayarlari',
        'parent_slug'   => 'site-ayarlari',
        'capability'    => 'manage_options',
        'redirect'      => false
    ));

}
```

Comment: Try the default first `if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) { acf_add_options_page(); }` See if that adds the Options page, then we can start getting into your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {
// add parent 
$parent = acf_add_options_page(array('page_title' => 'Theme Settings','menu_title' => 'Theme Settings',
'redirect' => false ));
}
```

Try like this

Comment: In function only one "acf_add_options_page" do try not more then one just for check

Answer (score 0):

You can add options page if you have `ACF PRO`. With only ACF you can't add options page.

And if you have ACF PRO then just paste below code in your `functions.php` file and try.

```
if( function_exists('acf_add_options_page') ) {

    acf_add_options_page();

}
```